# How do I test cookbooks in test kitchen that depend on tags?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, test-kitchen

I have a cookbook that depends on a tag. It searches for nodes with a given tag and gets their names and IPs using `search(:node, 'tag:MyTag')`. How would I mock this up in test kitchen?

Is there mock node objects I can use? It doesn't have to communicate with other nodes I just want to test that `search()` is successfully pulling down the right info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using serverspec, chef-zero will use the directory `test/integration/` as the default repo location. This is where you can place some node files to simulate other nodes connected to the same chef server.

```
├── Berksfile
├── chefignore
├── metadata.rb
├── README.md
├── recipes
│   └── default.rb
└── test
    └── integration
        ├── default
        │   └── serverspec
        │       └── default_spec.rb
        ├── helpers
        │   └── serverspec
        │       └── spec_helper.rb
        └── nodes
            ├── demo1.json
            └── demo2.json
```

### demo1.json

```
{
  "name": "demo1",
  "normal": {
    "tags": [
      "DEMO=1"
    ]
  }
}
```

### demo2.json

```
{
  "name": "demo2",
  "normal": {
    "tags": [
      "DEMO=1"
    ]
  }
}
```

---

### Update

I have a cookbook that tests Jenkins master and slaves using this technique

- https://github.com/myspotontheweb/chef-jenkins-farm

Comment: This is not specific to serverspec, and will work with both zero and solo provisioners.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you can edit your test kitchen.yml file's suite section for your node.  The attributes section manages your normal attributes which is where tags are stored:

```
- name: sand01
provisioner:
  name: chef_zero
attributes:
  tags:
    - MyTag
```